# What does "Bätschi" exactly mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, slang

"Bätschi" seems to be a quite popular word in German politics nowadays, being [popularized by](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xwUFhyI7u2U) the proposed new SPD head, Andrea Nahles. But I haven't been able to find a suitable explanation online, maybe because its popularity is too recent. Germans seem to find its meaning quite self-evident, and all the political talkshows or programs that I've seen just simply don't explain it.

What does "Bätschi" mean, exactly? And where did it come from?

Comment: I would not say it is popular only one politician is using it. It is really very childish speech.

Comment: It's popularity is not recent. I believe my parents have used it as children some 60 years ago. And I wouldn't be surprised if my grandparents have used it.

Comment: According to [this dictionary](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~%C3%84tsch,%20b%C3%A4tsch&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&suchspalte[]=rart_ou&suchspalte[]=rart_varianten_ou) it's (in variations) centuries old.

Comment: @Roland: that is for [*Ätsch*](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GA05951#XGA05951). with *Bätsch* it is more complicated.

Comment: She seems to be using it in an I-told-you-so manner or a now-you-have-the-schlamassel-without-us type of attitude.

Comment: Andrea Nahles is not the head of SPD. Olaf Scholz is atm.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It child's speech and often connected to *Ätsch* --> *Ätsch bätsch*. [Wiktionary (Ätsch)](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A4tsch)  is listing *Ätsch bätsch* as characteristic word combination.

*(Ätschi) Bätschi* is just another form with the same meaning.

Under "Ätsch" some explenations can be found in the internet for example on [Duden (Ätsch)](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aetsch):

> Ausruf zum Ausdruck des schadenfrohen Spotts (oft verbunden mit einer besonderen Geste)
>
> Translation: Exclamation to express the mischievous mockery (often combined with a special gesture)

[Wiktionary (Ätsch)](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A4tsch)  shows the additional meaning:

> Ich bin besser als du, ich kann mehr als du, ich habe mehr oder Besseres als du
>
> Translation: I am better than you, I am more capable than you, I own more or better things than you do

Comment: Swabian form: *Ätschgäbele!*

Comment: Pictures of typical gestures: [1](https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/12/11/34/240_F_12113479_WIqHCnGVSn3cheIRJvJ0ihpLgaZUgou2.jpg), [2](http://www.beautiful-life-magazin.com/cache/2b44a39b3e70c8d43f40856fef7a385a.jpg), [3](https://media.giphy.com/media/3ohjUPuneJ2Bi85tWE/giphy.gif) (a commentator in the national TV news!); 4 (no pic): stroking with the extended right index finger over the pointed left index finger several times

Answer (score 5):

*Bätschi* is used for a boring person in Swiss dialect:

[image]
<sup>[Schweizer Idiotiokon](https://digital.idiotikon.ch/idtkn/id_komplett.htm#!page/9967/mode/2up)</sup>

Obviously in the given context this was not the intended meaning but it may be worth to keep in mind when using it.

Other than that *bätsch* used as an interjection in the meaning of *ätsch* (Engl. *gotcha* or similar) is not new. The [DWDS references its usage](https://www.dwds.de/r?q=%22B%C3%A4tsch%22&corpus=kern&date-start=1900&date-end=1999&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=50) in letters of 1934 by Kurt Tucholsky but it most likely is much older than that.

Comment: Ist der Schweizer *Bätschi* verwandt mit dem bairischen *Batzi*? (Scheibweise kann wohl variieren; Bedeutung, nach meiner Erfahrung: ein ungeschickter, unangenehmer Mensch.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: eher nicht, denn der *Lumpazi* ist etymologisch wohl nicht Hintergrund des Schweizer *Bätschi* (aber eventuell das *Bätschi*, ein Schaf in der Schweizer Kindersprache).

Answer (score 3):

Those who are familiar with "The Simpsons" TV series there's a frequent exclamation of bully Nelson Mantz: "Ha-ha!" That is a close equivalent.

To expand it into real words Bätschi means something like "You want something, but you don't get it, and I enjoy that."

Answer (score 2):

The best English equivalent that I can find is "tee-hee". https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=teehee

It is a puerile phrase expressing schadenfreude. It does not have an actual literal meaning, i.e. it is not an actual word.

Comment: Why puerile? I hear this used by boys and girls likewise. Perhaps even more often by girls.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann “puerile” = “childish”. Girls can be puerile even if it seems that they should rather be puellile.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann this could certainly yield a wonderful discussion on Latin SE ;)

Answer (score -1):

Bätschi is more common in the southern parts of Germany (Ätsch being more common otherwise), it generally means as much as *"nah na na nah na"*. No adult person would use the expression, except maybe when talking to a three year old.

What it *really* means is the same thing as another Nahles quote: *"Ab Morgen gibt's auf die Fresse"*. The SPD, and Nahles in particular is not taking their responsibility seriously. The whole point of politics is to have your personal entertainment and to exchange petty insults. Riot, ideologic beacon projects and personal insults are more important than to provide the government that, as an elected representative, you owe to the citizens, or to make sensible decisions that affect the fates of millions of those same citizens.